# Creating side-by-side video from 2 separate files

Tags: video, flv

I'm writing an application that will require merging two separate videos (in .flv format) so that they play at the same time, side by side. Is there a good command line utility to do this? I would ideally like the output to be in .h264 format.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for AviSynth's StackHorizontal.
You will need to re-encode back to H.264, probably using x264.